# Display data in a section HTML

Tags: php, html, sidebar

I have an array I want to select and display data from it depending to criteria in the sidebar.
I would like the show this data in a section in the body, and a change will be made only for this section when I select a criteria on the sidebar.

For the moment my solution is to create a page for each criteria and connect it with link to the criteria in the sidebar.

Normally there is a solution to show it dynamically

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
 <body>
        <?php
        require_once ".\Classes\PHPExcel\IOFactory.php";
        $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("zfg01_CAT.xlsx");
        $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);
        include 'fonctionsUtiles.php';        
        afficherLesArticlesParGendre($sheet, "GARCON");       
        ?>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You would need to try a bit more than that and come back here with your trial. I would advise reading [this](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php), that will probably help. OH and if you really want to write function names in French and not in English (which is imho a bad idea as it will be very difficult to maintain by a non-french-speaking people, and probably disturbing to most others), I would advise using correct wording so that you don't confuse even the French-speaking ones : `Gendre` should be `Genre`

Comment: thank you for your response,
my web page is destinated only for french people so is not a problem to write it in french, also i corrected the word Genre I didn't make attention ;)
thanks